# EF7 rc1: Error on insert or update of entity with a computed column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I get the following error on insert or update of an entity with a computed column which gets value from a scalar function based on values from other tables.

> SqlException: Column 'inserted.SubjectStatus' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound. Consider removing the subquery or function from the column definition or removing the column from the OUTPUT clause.

My Entity (`Subject`) has property `SubjectStatus` with attribute `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)`.

Also, I have the following code on `DbModelBuilder`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
                    .Property(e => e.SubjectStatus)
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasComputedColumnSql("dbo.SubjectStatus(Id)")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

My search on the web didn't helped me. Is there any workaround?

Comment: It's a breaking change in ef core 7, so did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after updating from .net 6 to .net 7. It comes from a breaking change according to Microsoft's official documents:

[ef core 7.0 breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers)

For me the following change works:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Subject>()
        .Property(e => e.SubjectStatus)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("dbo.SubjectStatus(Id)");

    builder.Entity<Subject>()
        .ToTable(tbl => tbl.HasTrigger("dbo.SubjectStatus(Id)"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have created a computed column in the database and assigned a function to the column. Remove the function which is added against the column and just keep the column.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LMSFN_Course_GetEnrollmentCount] (@CourseID int)
RETURNS INT
```

Remove `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` from the property.

Also no need to add the attribute `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed).`